# Flask definition: Route and View

Tags: python, flask

Here is a minimal application with Flask:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

I know `index()` is the `view function`. **[Q1]** The question is, I can't tell exactly which part is `route` and which part is `view`. I didn't find the clarity definitions about them in Documentation.

**[Q2]** The wording below make me confused, which one is wrong?

- index view
- index route
- `/` route

**[Q3]** Could I say *the button below was ***pointed** to index ***view***?

```
<a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Button</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Q1: The function below `@app.route('/')` is the starting point of your website. Whenever your website is opened this is the code that gets executed. You can now add more app routes.

For example `@app.route('/contact')`. That means if you open your website the code below `@app.route('/')` gets executed but if you open *example.com/contact* the code of your /contact app route will be executed. The function name does not have to be index or contact. You can choose whatever name you want.

You can also add `href` tags to your HTML that refer to the desired app route. For example `<a href="./contact"></a>` will lead you to your contact app route when being clicked.

Q2: Depends on what you want to express. As I mentioned the function of `@app.route('/')` does not have to be index. You can put whatever function you want into that route.

Q3: '/' is your root url. This app route gets executed when you open example.com.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation, but what I want to know is the proper way of wording instead of how it work.

Comment: I think you have already answered your own question. In your example the function index() is the view and the line above is the route. In that case the first wording of Q2 would be wrong I guess.